# couldnt transfer data from spring controller to jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am stuck with this one spring example.I am getting data from user via jsp page and save method from the controller is evoked and the data is stored in the database through hibernateTemplate.save() method.I am able to achieve until this but when i try to display the data by passing the data to jsp i get http 404 error.My controller class is as follows

CController.java

```
import project4.UserDAO1;
import project4.User1;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;


@Controller


public class CController{

    private UserDAO1 userDAO;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDAO")
    private UserDAOImpl1 myUserDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO1 userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/frm4/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView add( @ModelAttribute("add") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
         request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("hai");

    userDAO.saveUser(user);
    System.out.println("hai");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/list.htm");
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("delete") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
        request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        userDAO.deleteUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }


    @RequestMapping(params = "find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView find(@ModelAttribute("find") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
         request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.findUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }


    @RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("update") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
        request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.updateUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User1());
        return new ModelAndView("list", modelMap);
     }
  }
```

My hibernateTemplate class is as follows

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package project4;
import project4.User1;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class UserDAOImpl1 implements UserDAO1 {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
  }

   @Override
   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
   public void saveUser(User1 user) {
      try {
       System.out.println (user.getId ());
      hibernateTemplate.save(user);
      }catch (RuntimeException re){
            throw re;
      }
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<User1> listUser() {
    List<User1> result = hibernateTemplate.find("from User1");
    System.out.println("hai");
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
  }

    @Override
  public void deleteUser(User1 user) {
    hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
  }

    @Override
    public List<User1> findUser(User1 user) {
        List<User1> result =hibernateTemplate.find("from User1 where USER_ID=:" 
                   +user.getId());
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User1 user) {
        hibernateTemplate.update(user);

    }

 }
```

and my jsp class where i am trying to display the list is as follows

list.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
   /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form:form method="POST">
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="50">Id</td>
        <td width="150">First Name</td>
         <td width="150">Last Name</td>
          <td width="100">Money</td>
           <td width="50">Currency</td>
        </tr>
   <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="person">
      <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${person.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.password}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.gender}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.country}" /></td>
        </tr>
     </c:forEach>
    </table>
   </form:form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

instead of using

```
  <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="person">
```

i have also tried with

```
  <c:forEach items="${user}" var="person">
```

and

```
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="person">
```

and my spring xml class is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema
          /jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema
        /tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema
        /util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema 
         /mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema
       /context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:annotation-config/>

<bean  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


<bean id="urlMapping"  
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>


        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean name="cController.do" class="project4.CController" >
  <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO"/>

</bean>


<bean name="indexController"  
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

this is only a part of the xml config file as i use two xml files.

I am able to save the data in the database but when i try to display the data i am getting the following error

```
type Status report

message /Spring/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp

description The requested resource (/Spring/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp) is not available.
```

and i am getting the url as

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring/list.htm
```

help needed plz

Comment: You are expecting a list in jsp. But you are not adding it into model in spring controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

You've got too much backslashes...

you wrote:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

but it has to be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

You aleady have this in your viewResolver

Comment: could you print the exact error message? (go to your serverlog and copy the exception which is thrown)

Comment: it says something like this "eclipse.buildId=M20090211-1700
java.version=1.6.0_03
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86


Error
Mon May 06 09:58:11 IST 2013
The 'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui.internal.hyperlink.script.event.JSPJavaHyperlinkDetector' extension from plug-in 'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui' to the 'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors' extension point will be ignored because it contains invalid attributes."